# Tensorflow with gradient decent results in wrong coefficients

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression, gradient-descent

Currently, i am trying to construct a linear regression that uses birth rate (x) as predictor to predict life expectancy (y).
y=w*x+b
The dataset could be found here: [Dataset](https://github.com/chiphuyen/stanford-tensorflow-tutorials/blob/master/examples/data/birth_life_2010.txt)

Here is an online link for my code: [Code](https://repl.it/repls/FrighteningRelievedKnowledge)

The idea is simple: i run 300 epochs, inside each epoch, i fed one-by-one paired sample (x value,y value) to the gradient decent optimizer to minimize loss function.

However, the result that i obtained is quite wrong.
Image of my result: [my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCaLV.png)

Instead of having negative slope, it always result in positive slope, while the sample answer provided [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kMGs68rIHWHifBiqlU3j_2ZkrNj9RquGTe8tJ7eR1sE/edit) results in a better model with negative slope.

What were wrong in my coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the location of the line

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

Since it is inside the while loop, `w` and `b` are reinitialized every iteration to 0. What you are seeing therefore is the result of one while loop iteration of training (the last one). You should move the line before the while loop.

Comment: Thank you, i solved it today. Oh my. it would be difficult without ur help